# How to copy over a position many time over while translating it in python?

Tags: python, loops

I have a unit cell with positions
0,0,0
0.5,0.5,0.5

I want to create a 5x5x5 matrix with points of the unit cell translated. The unit cell would move up/down/side to side by adding 1 to one of the three crystallographic positions. Currently I have a matlab code that does this manually but I would like to do this faster with a python loop.

```
what i have so far is basically 
0,0,0 +1,0,0=1,0,0
0,0,0 +0,1,0= 0,1,0
0,0,0 + 0,0,1=0,0,1
0,0,0 +2,0,0=2,0,0
0,0,0 +0,2,0= 0,2,0
0,0,0 + 0,0,2=0,0,2
and so on
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question for a bit? we might need some context and your effort to it.

Comment: Yes. It is basically taking a unit cell and translating it to create a super cell. So the original atom positions are 0,0,0 and by translating these up and down and side to side I want to create a bigger cell that is 5x5x5 rather than 1x1x1. Was this helpful?